# can I omit "which" here?

Tags: american-english

The original sentence is

> The apple which is lying on the table is mine

Can I shorten it to be

> The apple lying on the table is mine

I saw a expression describing RELATIVE CLAUSE on the random website, and they were like

> *if the relative pronoun is followed by a verb, the relative pronoun is a subject pronoun, subject pronoun must always be used*

But I think it's not the same thing, right?

First one is relative clause in opposition to the abbreviated sentence using participle clause grammar, is it not?

Comment: By the way,I posted this question using my phone. And i cannot find any formatting option or button as opposed to  computer version.i mean,english stack exchange APP.

Comment: Maybe you did this on your phone, but you can still use an upper-case "I" for the first person pronoun. Please don't use "I posted this on my phone" as an excuse for sloppy posts.

Comment: This is called [Whiz-Deletion](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/whiz-deletion/hot); for example, see http://english.stackexchange.com/a/50971/11482.

Comment: "...on *a* random website", BTW.

Comment: If the meaning of either phrase is the same, I would leave it out. In the first example, I would use *that* instead of *which*, but that is another topic.

Answer (score 3):

1. The apple which is lying on the table is mine.
2. The apple lying on the table is mine.

Both the sentences are grammatically correct; there's no difference in meaning. In the first sentence, "which is lying on the table is mine" is a relative clause.

In the second sentence, "lying on the table" is the reduced relative clause. You can reduce a relative clause  by omitting the relative pronoun and the auxiliary verb when the main verb in the relative clause is progressive.

Comment: The first sentence is not grammatically correct.  It should be: "The apple, which is lying on the table, is mine."

Comment: CluelessJoeJackson,  the relative clause " which is lying on the table" is a defining relative clause for which you don't use commas.

Comment: I think we need more context.  Is there more than one apple?

Answer (score 0):

They are both grammatically correct and both are not what a native English speaker would say. A more natural expression is:

> The apple on the table's mine.

Comment: I'd use the second one, actually (although maybe without 'lying').